# Mongoid duplicate fields query causes FieldPath field names may not contain '.'

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Seems this was broken in an upgrade from 3.0.x to 3.4.3 somewhere, we had a query to detect duplicate fields on a nested property:

```
Contact.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { machine_id: Machine.current.id } },
  { '$group' => { '_id' => { 'primary_email.email' => '$primary_email.email' }, 
  'uniqueIds' => { '$addToSet' => '$_id' }, count: { '$sum' => 1 } } },
  { '$match' => { count: { '$gt' => 1 } } }]).to_a
```

It looks like it fails due to primary_email.email which used to be valid, and used to correctly detect duplicate email fields across primary_email fields

I cannot figure out the new syntax to do this despite lots of trial and error

Comment: It will have nothing to do with the MongoDB version. What error "if any" is actually occurring? Can you at least demonstrate something that should be detected which is being ignored? It seems more of a process error than an issue with the statement itself though.

Comment: Actually I see the error, but there is no way this was **ever** allowed. You cannot use a "dotted" field name inside a nested key. So instead you should be writing `{ '$group' => { '_id' =>  '$primary_email.email' } }`. And it's also pointless to have a compound key when there is only one value.

Comment: Thanks Neil. This was absolutely working, around 3.0 - we moved from MongoLabs to Atlas and moved to 3.4 then and thats about the last time this was run.